# How to convert location name to location coordinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get latitude and longitude from location name using Google Maps API ?

If so how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is very well possible  .

make a get request to following URL and in response you will get the info you needed

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Rajkot,Gujarat,India&output=xml&oe=utf8&key=abcdefg
```

replace `Rajkot,Gujarat,India` with the place name you want to query

- [Document](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: Right link, wrong URL. It should be of the form http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode

Comment: they might have changed api, please refer to documents

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you mean 'address' when you say 'name'. Check [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use GeoCoder to convert name to latitude and longitude....Searchc GeoCoder now