# Convert area,city,state,country to latitude and longitude in googlep maps api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to get the latitude and longitude for a string which consists of areaname,cityname,statename and countryname using google maps api v3... How is it posssible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478316/how-to-convert-location-name-to-location-coordinates/6124099

Comment: @Colin Pickard its not duplicate .... what u pointed out is how to convert latlng to city name ? ... am asking reverse of that !!! i need city name to latlng

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer and comment when I realised I had read your question the wrong way round - it should be correct now.  cityname to latlong is called **geocoding** and latlong to cityname is called **reverse geocoding**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **[Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)**.

Here's an example request.  You need to separate the 4 sections of your location by commas:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kemp+Town,+Brighton,%20East%20Sussex,+UK&sensor=true
```

Comment: How to send variables in this api ? how to store the values ? will it return a json object ?